# How to export multiple functions Javacript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to export default all functions inside export default, but every time I try to import them in another file, I get the error that the functions don't exists. Am I importing wrong?

```
export default () => {

  // methods
  const makeRequest = async () => {

    async function useAllBenefits() {
      ...
    return payload;
    }

    async function useTopBenefits() {
     ...
    return payload;

    }

    // exposed
    return {
      useAllBenefits,
      useTopBenefits,
      makeRequest
    };
  };
}
```

myotherfile.js

```
import all from '../myFile'

console.log(all.useAllBenefits)
```

Comment: Your default export is a function. `all` is a function that doesn't return anything.

Comment: The entire point of `default` is to specify *one* thing as default. Your code will work but you have to use `all().useAllBenefits`

Comment: @ChrisG No, it won't. `all` doesn't return anything.

Comment: @jabaa — There **is** a `return` statement in the OP's code.

Comment: @Quentin `makeRequest` returns something useful, but `makeRequest` is a local variable in the exported function. The exported function doesn't contain a return statement.

Comment: @jabaa You're right, the structure is wrong. It does "work" like this though: https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-cdn-g05cv?file=/src/myFile.js (which is what I thought OP had done)

Comment: @jabaa — Ah, good point. I hadn't noticed that extra level of nesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to export multiple functions AS DEFAULT you can do it by exporting one object whose properties are functions.

```
export default {
   function1: () => {},
   function2: () => {},
   function3: () => {}
}
```

Now in another file you can import them and use as bellow:

```
import all from '../myFile.js';
all.function1();
all.function2();
```

Answer (score 4):

1. Don't put them inside another function
2. Use the `export` keyword

Such:

```
export const aFunction = () => {};
export const anOtherFunction = () => {};
const someDefaultExport = () => {};
export default someDefaultExport;
```

Then you can import them:

```
import theDefault, { aFunction, anOtherFunction } from "../myFile";
```

Answer (score 0):

Method 1. export each functions

myFunction.js

```
export const sum = (a,b) {
   return a + b;
}

export const multiply = (a,b) {
   return a * b;
}
```

Method 2.

myFunction.js

```
const sum = (a,b) {
   return a + b;
}

 const multiply = (a,b) {
   return a * b;
} 

export default {sum, multiply}
```

Import section

file.js

```
import all from './myFunction.js'

all.sum(10, 11);
```

Or
file.js

```
import {sum, multiply} from './myFunction.js'

sum(10, 11);
```